# AngularJS - how to filter by an array of integers in a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat and I was filtering it by a simple integer in this way:

view:

```
ng-repeat="t in vm.presencesByPerson | filter: vm.customfilter">
```

controller:

here I have a watcher on a dropdown, and based on the dropdown selection, it passes the selected value to be used as a filter:

```
this.customfilter = { person: { id: parseInt(filters[0])}};
```

I did it like this because the structure of `presencesByPerson` object is `[{person: {id, name, etc..}]`

this works correctly and `my ng-repeat` is filtered.

Now, instead of passing a single `id`, I want to pass an array of `id`'s, like this:

```
arrayID = [x, y, z]
```

so that it filters my ng-repeat by each value of the array!

how do I need to modify the code to make this work?

and I would like a type-script solution syntax as I m used to it!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change your customFilter object to function and filter with the `arrayID[]`

```
    this.customfilter = function(person) {
        if (arrayID.indexOf(person.id) != -1)
            return true;
    };
```

Hope It helps!!

```js
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.customfilter = function(person) {
        if (arrayID.indexOf(person.id) != -1)
            return true;
    };

    $scope.friends = [{ name: 'John', phone: '555-1276', id: 1 },
        { name: 'Mary', phone: '800-BIG-MARY', id: 2 },
        { name: 'Mike', phone: '555-4321', id: 3 },
        { name: 'Adam', phone: '555-5678', id: 4 },
        { name: 'Julie', phone: '555-8765', id: 5 },
        { name: 'Juliette', phone: '555-5678', id: 6 }
    ]

    arrayID = [1, 3, 6];    
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
    <table id="searchTextResults">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:customfilter">
            <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```